# Override system font with different font in Java

Tags: java, swing, fonts, custom-font

I am wondering how to override system font with a different font(having same name). From my research it appears that `GraphicsEnvironment#registerFont(font)` returns false in case of font name or font family name matches with already loaded system fonts.

Internally `GraphicsEnvironment` uses `SunFontManager` to register font.

```
    public boolean registerFont(Font font) {
    /* This method should not be called with "null".
     * It is the caller's responsibility to ensure that.
     */
    if (font == null) {
        return false;
    }

    /* Initialise these objects only once we start to use this API */
    synchronized (regFamilyKey) {
        if (createdByFamilyName == null) {
            createdByFamilyName = new Hashtable<String,FontFamily>();
            createdByFullName = new Hashtable<String,Font2D>();
        }
    }

    if (! FontAccess.getFontAccess().isCreatedFont(font)) {
        return false;
    }
    /* We want to ensure that this font cannot override existing
     * installed fonts. Check these conditions :
     * - family name is not that of an installed font
     * - full name is not that of an installed font
     * - family name is not the same as the full name of an installed font
     * - full name is not the same as the family name of an installed font
     * The last two of these may initially look odd but the reason is
     * that (unfortunately) Font constructors do not distinuguish these.
     * An extreme example of such a problem would be a font which has
     * family name "Dialog.Plain" and full name of "Dialog".
     * The one arguably overly stringent restriction here is that if an
     * application wants to supply a new member of an existing family
     * It will get rejected. But since the JRE can perform synthetic
     * styling in many cases its not necessary.
     * We don't apply the same logic to registered fonts. If apps want
     * to do this lets assume they have a reason. It won't cause problems
     * except for themselves.
     */
    HashSet<String> names = getInstalledNames();
    Locale l = getSystemStartupLocale();
    String familyName = font.getFamily(l).toLowerCase();
    String fullName = font.getFontName(l).toLowerCase();
    if (names.contains(familyName) || names.contains(fullName)) {
        return false;
    }

    /* Checks passed, now register the font */
    Hashtable<String,FontFamily> familyTable;
    Hashtable<String,Font2D> fullNameTable;
    if (!maybeMultiAppContext()) {
        familyTable = createdByFamilyName;
        fullNameTable = createdByFullName;
        fontsAreRegistered = true;
    } else {
        AppContext appContext = AppContext.getAppContext();
        familyTable =
            (Hashtable<String,FontFamily>)appContext.get(regFamilyKey);
        fullNameTable =
            (Hashtable<String,Font2D>)appContext.get(regFullNameKey);
        if (familyTable == null) {
            familyTable = new Hashtable<String,FontFamily>();
            fullNameTable = new Hashtable<String,Font2D>();
            appContext.put(regFamilyKey, familyTable);
            appContext.put(regFullNameKey, fullNameTable);
        }
        fontsAreRegisteredPerAppContext = true;
    }
    /* Create the FontFamily and add font to the tables */
    Font2D font2D = FontUtilities.getFont2D(font);
    int style = font2D.getStyle();
    FontFamily family = familyTable.get(familyName);
    if (family == null) {
        family = new FontFamily(font.getFamily(l));
        familyTable.put(familyName, family);
    }
    /* Remove name cache entries if not using app contexts.
     * To accommodate a case where code may have registered first a plain
     * family member and then used it and is now registering a bold family
     * member, we need to remove all members of the family, so that the
     * new style can get picked up rather than continuing to synthesise.
     */
    if (fontsAreRegistered) {
        removeFromCache(family.getFont(Font.PLAIN));
        removeFromCache(family.getFont(Font.BOLD));
        removeFromCache(family.getFont(Font.ITALIC));
        removeFromCache(family.getFont(Font.BOLD|Font.ITALIC));
        removeFromCache(fullNameTable.get(fullName));
    }
    family.setFont(font2D, style);
    fullNameTable.put(fullName, font2D);
    return true;
   }
```

source: https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/font/SunFontManager.java 
Line no 3001

Comment: *"override system font with a different font(having same name)"* ... ***Why?***

Comment: I want to load my own font. And if system has already font with the same name then this method does not allow to register the font.

Comment: *"And if system has already font with the same name.."* ..then it should be the same font, and look the same. Why change it to a different copy of the same font?

Comment: I have an application which supports different OS I want to have look and feel same for all OS. So I want to ship default fonts which can be loaded instead of system fonts. I have faced an issue in which font with same name is different in different systems.

Comment: `I have faced an issue in which font with same name is different in different systems.` - well users of the LAF are used to the look of the font on that system, so you should not be trying to change the look. Just make sure you use layout managers and all components will display properly.

Comment: I agree with you. But as a developer, I would like that LAF of my application should be the same independent of the OS.

Comment: *"I agree with you."* Who do you agree with? Tip: Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"But as a developer,"* You say that like you're the only developer here. Funny.. *"I would like that LAF of my application should be the same independent of the OS."* As an experienced developer, I realise that what most users want is a GUI that looks and behaves most like their native apps. - a L&F that they are used to.

Comment: I agree with @camickr. That L&F are used to be look of the font on the system. This does not help. 
But I have the requirement to have same L&F on all system. 
I have faced issue while a font is not rendered properly because there are already fonts present in the system. And I can not uninstall the already existing fonts in the system because it can be used by some other applications.

Comment: This is a good question, the application could supply an enhanced font with additional glyphes compared to the one installed on the system.